# Sound hardware is detected but keyboard buttons, panel icon buttons don't work

Tags: 11.10, sound

I have 64-but Ubuntu 11.10. The sound works fine, but the keyboard sound keys don't work. The sound icon on the top panel also doesn't work. Also no hardware devices & Running applications are shown in the Sound settings.

**Screenshot 1:**

[image]

**Screenshot 2:**

[image]

Results of some commands that might help:

```
$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Dell Device 02be
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    Memory at fc500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

--
01:00.1 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc RV710/730
    Subsystem: Dell Device 02be
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    Memory at fc010000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [Intel          ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel
                      HDA Intel at 0xfc500000 irq 46
 1 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI HDMI
                      HDA ATI HDMI at 0xfc010000 irq 47
```

I think some packages are missing. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Haven't found the solution yet. But for the time being, I'm using **Alsamixer** to control the volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what i tried...
1. rm -rvf ~/.pulse/

Reboot

No success

1. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

Run this command
sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils gdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils gdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.pulse*; sudo usermod -aG `cat /etc/group | grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e '^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's:,$::g'` `whoami`

as I was having 11.10

Reboot

Guess what.. it worked like ever before :)

Kamal

Answer (score 0):

I've got also the same problem with my sound card. But there's no sound at all.
System is 32bit Ubuntu 11.04 with gnome-shell 3.3.2.

```
$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
Audio device: nVidia Corporation MCP55 High Definition Audio (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. Device 7250
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 20
    Memory at fbef0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel

$ cat /proc/asound/cards 
 0 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xfbef0000 irq 20
```

After type `$ sudo alsa reload` device shows up in Sound settings, but theres still no sound.

Comment: Read Kamal's solution. It works. For Ubuntu 11.04 follow the link that he has posted.